# Can someone please translate this for me?

Tags: translation

[image]

Can someone please translate this into English for me?

Comment: Very badly written by the way. The second laam is much too short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means " with name of Allah the most  beneficent, the most merciful "

You should use this phrase when you start any activity, work or anything

Comment: Thank you! So for a student, it would make sense to write this on all of their papers they turn in to their professor?

Comment: @Curious - most people just say it silently to themselves but it looks like this particular student wrote it out.

Comment: @Curious Depends on the university policy and the professor's leniency.

Comment: @Curious - I know many students who do that.

Comment: @Curious Not particularly. Students usually do it in hopes that Allah will make them pass, a form of shirk. It is required to be said but not written. Many scholars say that those who write it on school papers are sinners since it doesn't get the respect it earns.

Answer (score -4):

Qalima-e-tauheed                       I bear witness that no one is worthy of worship expect allah and i bear witness that muhammad sallahualehi-wa-sallam is him slave and messanger

Comment: The Answer is incorrect, as the sentence in the question is not the kalima but البسملة (the Basmala)